# Closing input in CLIPS

Tags: input, console, clips

I am making a program in CLIPS and I am trying that when a certain rule is executed, the user can't add more facts from the CLIPS console. I was wondering if there is a command for either closing the input of the console without closing it or preventing to add more facts, I tried close, exit and halt but they are not what I am looking for. Anybody knows? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no built-in functionality for disabling entry of commands at the command prompt. Typically end users don't directly interact with a program by entering commands to assert facts at the command prompt. Rules prompt the user for input and assert facts based on that input. Entering commands at the command prompt is typically used for debugging and development. A deployed application that wants to deny the user access to the command prompt would embed the application within a C program and use API calls to load and start execution of the program.